# Find a vector from some conditions

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I need help with this exercise, does anyone know how to do it ?

> Find a vector U perpendicular to W = (0,1, 0) ,with modulo 3 and that
>   has an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with the vector V = (1, $\sqrt 2$, 1).
>   Is it unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your vector U is given by
$$U = (x,y,x)$$
Then the first condition can be written as
$$U\cdot W = 0 = 0x + 1y +0z \Rightarrow y=0$$
So now
$$U = (x,0,z)$$
And we have
$$||U|| = 3 = \sqrt{x^2+z^2}$$
And also
$$\frac{U\cdot V}{||U||\ ||V||} = \cos{\frac{\pi}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x+z}{3*2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow x+z = 3$$
$$\Rightarrow z = 3-x$$
Going back to the condition on the modulus,
$$9 = x^2 + (3-x)^2 = x^2 + 9 -6x + x^2 = 2x^2-6x+9$$
$$2x^2 - 6x = 0 = 2x(x-3)$$
So we have two solutions:
(0,0,3) and (3,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Try finding an equation for a vector $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies each condition individually, then solving the resulting system of equations.

For example, the condition "$U$ is perpendicular to $W$" is solved by $$y = 0$$ The vectors satisfying this condition are on the $xz$-plane. We know that the inner product of $V$ and $U$ is $|V||U|\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) = 2*3*\frac{1}{2} = 3$, so $$x + y\sqrt{2} + z = 3$$ By substituting in the first condition we get $$x + z = 3$$ We also have $$|U| = \sqrt{x^2 + z^2} = 3$$
Substituting in $z = 3-x$, we get $$3=\sqrt{x^2 + (3-x)^2} = \sqrt{2x^2 - 6x + 9}$$ This has solutions at $x = 0$ and $x = 3$. Thus, we have $(0,0,3)$ and $(3,0,0)$